# Inno Setup generated installer does not show "Select Destination Location" page on some systems

Tags: inno-setup

I create my application with `py2exe` and package it into an installer exe using Inno Setup on Windows 7. The installer created this way can then be installed on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 systems. When it works, the installer shows following screens in sequence:

1. Welcome screen
2. EULA screen
3. default (or previous install) location, allowing user to select new install location,
4. Confirming install location, and
5. usual install screens.

This is the behavior I get with **Inno Setup 5.5.5** or lower.

With **Inno Setup 5.5.7** and higher (did not try 5.5.6), the installer is created normally and can be setup as above on Windows 7. However, the same installer fails to show screens 1 and 3 from above list during setup on Windows 10: setup directly starts with EULA screen and then jumps to confirm install location. The confirm screen doesn't even show which directory the installation will be done.

Continuing allows the installation to happen in the default location and the application works normally. Not knowing the install location is highly annoying and undesirable.

The `.iss` file that I use (see below) is identical across the different Inno Setup versions that I have tried. In the file, the `DefaultDirName` is set explicitly (based on the version of the application).

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp
AppVersion=2.0.1
AppVerName=MyApp 2.0.1
DefaultDirName=C:\MyApp_v2.0.1

[Files]
Source: "MyApp_main.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

I also tried packaging the installer with Inno Setup (5.5.7 and 5.5.9) on Windows 10, but it had the same behavior.

I was wondering it I need to set additional parameters for the installer to work correctly on Windows 10 also for newer versions of Inno Setup?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Quoting [revision history for Inno Setup 5.5.7](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.7):

> As recommended by Microsoft's desktop applications guideline, `DisableWelcomePage` now defaults to `yes`. Additionally `DisableDirPage` and `DisableProgramGroupPage` now default to `auto`. The defaults in all previous versions were `no`.

---

Conclusion:

- The Welcome page is not shown anymore by default. To enable it, set the [`DisableWelcomePage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablewelcomepage):

  ```
  DisableWelcomePage=no
  ```

  *I do not think you are right with your statement that the page shows on Windows 7.*
- The "Select Destination Location" page is shown for fresh installations only, not for "upgrades". So this has nothing to do with Windows 7 vs. Windows 10. The difference is probably that you have the application installed on Windows 10 system; and you do not have it installed on the Windows 7 system.

  To show the page always, set the [`DisableDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage):

  ```
  DisableDirPage=no
  ```

---

Thought as mentioned in the quote above, the defaults are recommended, so you should follow them.

Comment: Thanks Martin. As you rightly guessed I had the app installed on Win 10, but not on Win 7. I will change defaults and try again.

Answer (score 4):

I found another parameters that affects it.

```
CreateAppDir=no
```

In [CreateAppDir](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createappdir) page says:

> If this is set to no, no directory for the application will be created, the *Select Destination Location* wizard page will not be displayed, and the {app} directory constant is equivalent to the {win} directory constant. If the uninstall feature is enabled when `CreateAppDir` is no, the uninstall data files are created in the system's Windows directory.

Comment: OK, but this does not answer the question. There's no `CreateAppDir=no` in the script and the question says *"on some systems"*.

Answer (score 1):

here I used

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=No
```

by default this parameter is seted to ***auto***.

> If this is set to auto, at startup Setup will look in the registry to
> see if the same application is already installed, and if so, it will
> not show the Select Destination Location wizard page.

See more in https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage

Comment: Yes, but that's what [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38709331/850848#38714576) says already.

Comment: you didn't say the group is [Setup]