# inno setup, defining second page with select directory option hides wpSelectDir page

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create installer which would consist of standard pages + would contain one additional page which allows user to define folder where files needed for application would be stored, this page should go after standard select directory page, so I created the following script:

```
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DataDir: String;


begin
  // Create the page
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select Personal Data Location', 'Where should personal data files be stored?',
    'Personal data files will be stored in the following folder.'#13#10#13#10 +
    'To continue, click Next. If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse.',
    False, 'New Folder');

  // Add item (with an empty caption)
  Page.Add('');

  // Set initial value (optional)
  Page.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\My Company\My Program');
  // Read value into variable
  DataDir := Page.Values[0];
end
```

When I run the installer I see that it contains my custom `CreateInputDirPage` page but original `CreateInputDirPage` is missing (despite the fact that I specified  `CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,...)` i.e. my custom select dir page should go after standard one).

Seems like `CreateInputDirPage()` replaces original page with custom, is there any way to have multiple CreateInputDirPages?

Thanks very much,
Andrey

Answer (score 0):

When user creates custom `selectDirPage` to allow the standard one it's needed to define the following configuration in `[Setup]` section:

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=no
```

Otherwise standard `selectDirPage`  will be hidden

Comment: That's not true. Your problem has nothing to do with the custom page. Read again my answer in [Inno Setup generated installer does not show "Select Destination Location" page on some systems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38709331/850848). Please accept the duplicate instead of posting wrong answers.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I'm not sure what systems you talked about, I have Inno Setup 5 and previously, before I added second selectDirPage, standard selectDirPage had been shown (without explicitly adding DisableDirPage=no). But then, after I added second selectDirPage, it disappeared and I had to explicitly add DisableDirPage=no to show it again. That's why I think we are talking about different stuff.

Comment: Because you already have the application installed. Even if you remove the custom page code, the standard directory page won't display. But if you uninstall the application, the standard directory page will display, no matter, if the custom page code is present or not.

Comment: As my answer in the duplicate question says: *The "Select Destination Location" page is shown for fresh installations only, not for "upgrades". .. The difference is probably that you have the application installed [now]....*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I'll remove custom page to check and DisableDirPage=no to ensure that I'm not mistaking. If I'm, then I'll edit my answer

Comment: No, you should accept the duplicate or delete your question. Answering a question that's wrong does not make sense. Because it's not true that *"defining second page with select directory option hides wpSelectDir page"*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I checked  this, you're right