# Directory confirmation dialog window in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, setup-project

I wanna know how to add that directory confirmation dialog window, where it's showing the main path but the user can still change it and apply it to this code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.0.0
DefaultGroupName=Test
OutputBaseFilename=Test
DisableWelcomePage=no
 
[Components]
Name: "Format1";     Description: "Format1";      
Name: "Format2";     Description: "Format2";     
 
[Files]
Source: "I:\Format1.dll";  DestDir: "{app}\Test\Format1"; Flags:; Components: Format1
Source: "I:\Format2.dll";  DestDir: "{app}\Test\Format2"; Flags:; Components: Format2
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? [Inno Setup generated installer does not show "Select Destination Location" page on some systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38709331/850848)

Answer (score 3):

By *directory confirmation dialog window* you mean the Inno's standard **Directory page**? Use:

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=no
```

Default value is **auto** so force this value to **no** to always show the page, see the doc:

> `[Setup]`: `DisableDirPage` Valid values:  `auto`, `yes`, or `no`   Default
> value:  `auto`
> Description:
> If this is set to `yes`, Setup will not show the **Select Destination Location** wizard page.
> If this is set to `auto`, at startup Setup will look in the registry to see if the same application is already installed, and if so, it will not show the **Select Destination Locatio**n wizard page.
> Also see `AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage`.

[More details in online Inno help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_disabledirpage.htm)

[image: Directory page]

Comment: I want the components to have standard paths and when the user click next they will get the option to either keep the standard path or change it, please see the attached screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYJ2M.jpg

Comment: @Ramzi Side point: If a user has already installed it and now you let them pick new path in upgrade, what happens to all the data in the old path?

Comment: @Ramzi If you want that, I believe your question needs significant edit for clarification, as obviously no one has understood it (and I have already wrote that to you in a comment to your now-deleted "answer") + I wonder, who and why might have upvoted your unclear question.

Comment: @Ramzi If you have another question feel free to post it and mark this as an answer