# Install two files into a user selected directory

Tags: inno-setup

I want to install two files into a installation directory. The directory shall be selected by the user during installation and shall be created if it does not exist. A default path shall be proposed.

What I have so far is:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=Testapp
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={code:GetOtherDir}
DefaultGroupName=TestProgram
PrivilegesRequired = lowest
OutputBaseFilename =TestProgram

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "program.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "readme.txt";  Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\Subdirectory"; Filename: "{userdocs}\Subdirectory\program.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Code]
var
  OtherInputDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OtherInputDirPage :=
    CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir, 'Installationsverzeichnis wählen:', '', '', False, '');
  OtherInputDirPage.Add('');
  // Set initial value (optional)
  OtherInputDirPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Subdirectory');
end;

function GetOtherDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := OtherInputDirPage.Values[0];
end;
```

I am able to install one single file into a user defined location with a different code, but I am not able to use that location also for the second file, so this is why I came up with the code above. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you creating `OtherInputDirPage`? Why don't you use the standard "Select directory" page?  + Which is the *"second file"* that does not install? Post a log fle.

Comment: Sorry, but can you please point me to any sort of sample code for the standard page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying seems unnecessarily complicated for such a trivial task. A basic Inno Setup script for installing two files into user-selected directory is like:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={autopf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "program.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

---

You possibly got confused, because you have the application installed already and the standard directory selection page does not show. See:
[Inno Setup generated installer does not show "Select Destination Location" page on some systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38709331/850848)

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Martin Prikryl was rather helpful, and my additional problem was actually that the DisableDirPage=no was missing and therefore the directory selection dialog did not show up since the program was already installed once.

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={userdocs}\Testprogramdir
//DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage = yes
DisableDirPage = no
OutputDir=Output

[Files]
Source: "program.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  InstallDir: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then begin
    InstallDir := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
    if not DirExists(InstallDir) then begin
      if not CreateDir(InstallDir) then begin
        MsgBox('Could not create installation directory.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := InstallDir; // Update the directory edit field
  end;
end;
```

Comment: 1) Why do you want the `DisableDirPage=no`? 2) What's the point of your `NextButtonClick`? Inno Setup creates the folder for you. + Imo, the `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := InstallDir` does not do anything.

Comment: The underlying problem is more complicated, since I am looking for a way to adapt the icon name, but I have opened a new topic with a refined question on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095282/create-adapted-desktop-icon-when-install-files-into-a-user-selected-directory

Comment: That's still imo does not explain what is your `NextButtonClick` for.

Comment: Moreover if the point of the `DisableDirPage=no` is that you want to install the same program multiple times, then you are only hiding away the problem that you install all instances using the same `AppId`, so you will be only able to install the last installed copy.

Comment: Regarding `NextButtonClick`: Since I wanted to modify the link name on the desktop, my understanding was that I need some sort of variable in a function which extracts the name from the directory name and uses it to modify the link name on the desktop. The only way to create a variable is a function, so I started with `NextButtonClick`. In the end I found a more elegant way in the other post.

Comment: Regarding `DisableDirPage=no`: Do you mean _deinstall the last copy_? This is fine for me, I am no heavy user, this is a quick and dirty solution for a rather time consuming problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Regarding `NextButtonClick` – but the desktop icon is not part of THIS question. So the `NextButtonClick` function is only confusing here.

Comment: Regarding `DisableDirPage=no` – if you prefer quick and dirty solutions for you personally, that's your choice, but if you want to suggest your solution publicly, you should at least acknowledge that it's quick and dirty.