# Create adapted desktop icon when installing files into a user selected directory

Tags: inno-setup

I want to install two files into a installation directory. The directory shall be selected by the user during installation and shall be created if it does not exist. A default path shall be proposed.

At the same time, an icon shall be placed on the desktop which includes information on the previously defined path (basically, I want to install the same files multiple times for different users, and both the directory name and the icon description shall show the user name)

Based on a previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065369/install-two-files-into-a-user-selected-directory/78065546#78065546), what I have so far is:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={userdocs}\Testprogramdir
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage = yes
DisableDirPage = no
OutputDir=Output
DefaultGroupName=Testgroup
PrivilegesRequired = lowest
OutputBaseFilename =Testsetupfile

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "program.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "readme.txt";  Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\program - username"; Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  InstallDir: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then begin
    InstallDir := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
    if not DirExists(InstallDir) then begin
      if not CreateDir(InstallDir) then begin
        MsgBox('Could not create installation directory.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := InstallDir; // Update the directory edit field
  end;
end;
```

How do I get the information on the directory name which was entered in the select wizard and is stored in the `{app}` variable to show up in the `[Icons]` section, instead of the hard coded `"program - username"` description?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution myself, thanks for the discussions:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={userdocs}\Testprogramdir
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage = yes
DisableDirPage = no
OutputDir=Output
DefaultGroupName=Testgroup
PrivilegesRequired = lowest
OutputBaseFilename =Testsetupfile
UsePreviousAppDir = no


[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; 

[Files]
Source: "program.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "readme.txt";  Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{code:Name}"; Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Code]
function Name(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  Result := ExtractFileName(Result);
end;
```

Comment: `''+` does not do anything. Remove that.

Comment: Imo, you need to set `AppId` to unique name. See also my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78065369/850848#comment137678210_78065553

Comment: I am copying identical exe files to different data directories, together with other data. The `AppId` is not used. This may be bad practice, but in this special case it is helpful.

Comment: How is it helpful?

Comment: I am installing exe files of a program which trains exercises with pupils at school. the data for the program is stored in a database. The program shall be executable with local access privileges (therefore I need to install it a subfolder of the documents directory), and there need to be multiple subdirectories for different pupils, since they do not have their own user accounts. Very bad practice, but I cannot chance the way schools are operating.